# NSArray With NSString Is This Even Possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to build a Grouped Sectioned View. I want to set an array as an object in the dictionary but I came across the empty array Issues.
Is this Even possible????? Is There a trick ????

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Get the specific Node for this row.
    Nodes *nodes = (Nodes *)[nodesMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Create the Details View Controller and initialize it. 
    nodesDetailView *viewController = [[nodesDetailView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped ];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];   

    // Set the title of the view to the nodes name
    viewController.title = [nodes computer_name];
    //Information
    //Network Data
    viewController.ipaddress= [nodes ipaddress];
    viewController.subnet_mask= [nodes subnet_mask];
    viewController.gateway= [nodes gateway];
    viewController.domain_name= [nodes domain_name];
}

#import "nodesDetailViewController. h


@interface nodesDetailView : UITableViewController{

//Network Data
NSString *ipaddress;
NSString *subnet_mask;
NSString *gateway;
NSString *domain_name;

//Grouped 
NSMutableArray *Keys;
NSMutableDictionary *Contents;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *Keys;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *Contents;



@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ipaddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subnet_mask;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *gateway;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *domain_name;



@end

#import "nodesDetailViewController. m


@synthesize .......


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {

    NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    NSString *network = @"Network Data";
    NSString *product = @"Product Details";

  //IS THIS POSSIBLE ??????? Because I get An Empty array 
    [contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ipaddress,subnet_mask, gateway, domain_name, nil] forKey:network];

 return self;
}
```

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: please make your question clear...

Comment: NSlog it and I get The content of arry is{
    "General Information" =     (
    );
    "Network Data" =     (
    );
    "Product Details" =     (
    );
}

Comment: please add the code where you are accessing this array. As far as i know your array inside your dictionary is fine but you are accessing it the wrong way.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 
 NSString *key = [[self sectionKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *contents = [[self sectionContents] objectForKey:key];
  
 return [contents count];

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Those Who are wondering: Problem Solved My code was fine. the problem was : 
it was in the wrong place.

The Code Supposed to be in - (void)viewDidLoad and not in - (id)initWithStyle:

I want to thank everybody who took the time to look in to it. 
I have no idea why  i put the code there to begin with.

Thanx Again

Answer (score 0):

All of those strings that you are adding to the array haven't even been allocated/initialized yet. That's why the array is empty. You can't just go: `NSString *emptyString;` and then go: `[myArray addObject:emptyString];`. Your strings are all empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values u are passing from the table view. They maybe nil. I just used this much of data and i m getting correct NSLog.

```
NSMutableDictionary *contents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *my = @"kk";
NSString *my1 = @"polko";
[contents setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: my1,my, nil] forKey:@"o"];
NSLog(@"%@" , contents);
```

Comment: I did that already and it works. The problem is that it does not work with viewController.ipaddress= [nodes ipaddress]; ipaddress inside the array gives me nothing. However If I create a UILabel and do something like headerLabel.text = ipaddress; works fine Why is not working within the Array ???

Comment: you are having [nodes ipaddress] as nil.. ?
have you NSLog this statement